# Why is following Java naming conventions not required for compilation

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Why is it not needed for a Java application to follow the Java naming conventions? In other words, why doesn't the Java compiler raise an error when the conventions are not followed in an application? It would certainly make the life of every programmer easier if no code would exist that contains, for example, class names starting with a lower-case letter or package names starting with an upper-case letter.

I understand that it is not possible to start requiring this now, because that would break existing applications, but why has this not been required from the beginning?

Comment: May be you should ask this on [programmer.SE]

Comment: Conventions are not rules.  They are more like guidelines.

Comment: Why do they need to be compiler rules? What if I want to make my own rules? What if in one particular case it actually makes more sense to not follow the naming convention? The point of compiler rules is that without them it would be **impossible** to run the program. Names can suck, but you can still work with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it not needed for a Java application to follow the Java naming conventions?

Because they're *conventions* rather than *rules*. It would be very odd for naming conventions to be enshrined in a language specification as actual rules - I don't think I've *ever* seen that. Naming it seen to be primarily a developer's choice, with some suggestions to make things more consistent between other developers.

Any Java compiler which refused to compile unconventional code would be violating the Java Language Specification.

Would you also suggest that brace formatting should be enforced by the compiler? How about the ordering of import statements?

While I would certainly recommend that Java developers *should* follow the naming conventions - at least wherever reasonable (there can be odd capitalization cases which make this difficult... anything around `iPhone` for example could look odd one way or another) I would be against them being proscribed as "law" in the language specification.

Answer (score 0):

`Because Code conventions are nothing to compilers.`

> Code conventions followed by programmers to to help improve the readability of their source code and make software maintenance easier.Coding conventions are only applicable to the human maintainers and peer reviewers of a software project.Coding conventions are not enforced by compilers.
>
> As a result, not following some or all of the conventions has no impact on the executable programs created from the source code.